# Run preprocessor using nbconvert as a library

Tags: jupyter-notebook, nbconvert

I would like to run nbconvert with a preprocessor that removes cells marked with the tag "skip". I am able to do this from the command line, but when I try to use the nbconvert API within a notebook I run into problems.

## An example

Following the example in the [documentation](https://nbconvert.readthedocs.io/en/latest/nbconvert_library.html#Quick-overview), I get a notebook to work with.

```
from urllib.request import urlopen

url = 'http://jakevdp.github.com/downloads/notebooks/XKCD_plots.ipynb'
response = urlopen(url).read().decode()

import nbformat
nb = nbformat.reads(response, as_version=4)
```

I'll modify one cell so it gets skipped in the output.

```
nb.cells[1].metadata = {'tags': ['skip']}
```

### Command line

Saving the file, and then running nbconvert from the command line:

```
nbformat.write(nb, 'nb.ipynb')

%%bash
jupyter nbconvert --to latex \
--TagRemovePreprocessor.remove_cell_tags='{"skip"}' \
--TagRemovePreprocessor.enabled=True \
'nb.ipynb'
```

This works. The output `nb.tex` file does not contain the cell tagged "skip".

### API

Now let's try it using the API instead. First, without any preprocessing:

```
import nbconvert
latex, _ = LatexExporter().from_notebook_node(nb)
print(latex[:25])
```

> \documentclass[11pt]{arti

Again, no problem. The conversion is working.

Now, trying to use the same preprocessor I used from the command line:

```
from traitlets.config import Config

c = Config()
c.RemovePreprocessor.remove_cell_tags = ('skip',)
c.LatexExporter.preprocessors = ['TagRemovePreprocessor']

LatexExporter(config=c).from_notebook_node(nb)
```

This time, I get:

> ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'TagRemovePreprocessor'

As far as I can see, this code matches the [code sample in the documentation](https://nbconvert.readthedocs.io/en/latest/removing_cells.html#removing-pieces-of-cells-using-cell-tags), except that I'm using the Latex exporter instead of HTML. So why isn't it working?

Answer (score 3):

For your particular case, I believe you can resolve the issue by changing: `c.RemovePreprocessor.remove_cell_tags = ('skip',)` -> 
`c.TagRemovePreprocessor.remove_cell_tags = ('skip',)`

---

For the benefit of others that come across this thread as I did by searching

```
ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'TagRemovePreprocessor'
```

There is an [open issue](https://github.com/jupyter/nbconvert/issues/764) with `TagRemovePreprocessor` that causes all exporters other than the `HTMLExporter` (and `LatexExporter`?) to automatically disable this preprocessor.

In my case, I was attempting to use the `NotebookExporter` and needed to explicitly enable the preprocessor and change the preprocessing level like so:

```py
import json
from traitlets.config import Config
from nbconvert import NotebookExporter
import nbformat

c = Config()
c.TagRemovePreprocessor.enabled=True # Add line to enable the preprocessor
c.TagRemovePreprocessor.remove_cell_tags = ["del_cell"]
c.preprocessors = ['TagRemovePreprocessor'] # Was previously: c.NotebookExporter.preprocessors

nb_body, resources = NotebookExporter(config=c).from_filename('notebook.ipynb')
nbformat.write(nbformat.from_dict(json.loads(nb_body)),'stripped_notebook.ipynb',4)
```

Comment: Thanks. I also had to change `c.LatexExporter.preprocessors` to `c.preprocessors` as in your example.

Comment: and you can even do it to the same notebook from which you remove the tagged cell (here: "del_cell")!